# Derivation of the bivariate normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I am reading through a [derivation](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/412332.pdf)  of the bivariate normal distribution, (from the US Defence Department!) and came across an expression that I can't understand.

The derivation starts off with the observation that the total area, $A$, under the curve of the distribution is $1$, since it is a probability distribution.  Also, the distribution can be expressed as a differential equation:

$$dy=-k \ xy \ dx \tag{1}$$

$$y= Ce^{-k{x^2\over2}} \tag{2}$$

$$A= C\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-k{x^2\over2}}  \tag{3}$$

Using integration by parts, the text proceeds to evaluate

$$A= C|e^{-k{x^2\over2}}|_{-\infty}^{\infty}+C\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2e^{-k{x^2\over2}}  \tag{4}$$

(I skipped some steps for brevity. Please tell me if that creates confusion.)

Then the text says the following line:

> Since the first expression takes an indeterminate form, new
>   numerators and denominators are obtained by independent derivatives, and the
>   limiting value of the expression then becomes zero. Since, by definition,
>   the n-th moment of a frequency distribution is defined as
>
> $$\text {n-th moment} = \int_{b}^{a}x^n f(x)dx$$
>
> and since from fundamental principles the standard deviation is the square
>   root of the second moment about the mean, then it follows, considering $(3)$,
>   that the second expression in $(4)$ becomes 
>   $$A=Ak\sigma_X^2 \tag{5}$$

I think I understand how we got rid of the first expression  $C|e^{-k{x^2\over2}}|_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ in $(4)$, but what I don't understand is, how does this last step, $(5)$, follow from the previous steps? Also, where did the $C$ go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$C$ is part of $f(x)$ as can be seen in step $(3)$ if one would just put it in front of the integral sign, and is therefore part of the variance, $σ_X^2$. $A$ is just $1$. The point of this step is to prove that $k={1\over σ_X^2}$